# When do apt-mark show architecture in package name?

Tags: apt, architecture

Here apt-mark shows architecture only for i386 package, and does not show i386 package, if it is not specified as such:

```
$ apt-mark showmanual libfontconfig1
libfontconfig1
$ apt-mark showmanual libfontconfig1:amd64
libfontconfig1
$ apt-mark showauto libfontconfig1
$ apt-mark showauto libfontconfig1:i386
libfontconfig1:i386
$ apt-mark showmanual libfontconfig1:i386
$ apt-mark showauto libfontconfig1:amd64
```

Is amd64 assumed, if it is the architecture of the OS? How do you get the architecture?

This is in Ubuntu 14.04. Does it work differently in newer releases?

Comment: I made a bug report about the behavior of apt-mark: see [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1576960).

Answer (score 0):

apt-mark shows architecture, if the package has different architecture than the native architecture of the OS.